# 'OpenloginAdapter' is not assignable to type 'IAdapter<unknown>' using Safe{Core} Auth Kit

Tags: gnosis-safe, web3auth

I'm following the example in the [safe docs](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/web3auth), but when I create and instance of OpenloginAdapter and I try to assign it as adapter in the web3AuthmodalPack initialization, the types are not assignable. I dont know if maybe I need a specific version of web3Auth or something like that. Thank u.

[image: Error Descripcion:]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I adjusted my package versions to the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@web3auth/base": "^4.3.0",
    "@web3auth/modal": "^4.3.1",
    "@web3auth/openlogin-adapter": "^4.3.0",
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.3.0",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^1.2.0",
    "@walletconnect/client": "^1.8.0",
    "@safe-global/auth-kit": "^1.2.0",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
}
```

This worked for me.

I grabbed these versions from https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/auth-kit/package.json

I hope this works for you!